# how to capture video from webcam in MJPG opencv

Tags: usb, video, webcam, display-resolution, opencv

I have bought the two of [Genius facecam 1000x](http://www.geniusnet.com/Genius/wSite/ct?xItem=55382&ctNode=161) camera and trying to set up a stereo camera, the `v4l2-ctl` outputs for cameras are as follow:

```
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Index       : 0
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
    Name        : YUYV 4:2:2

    Index       : 1
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'MJPG' (compressed)
    Name        : Motion-JPEG
```

As you can see the pixel format MJPG is supported and from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781770/capturing-multiple-webcams-uvcvideo-with-opencv-on-linux) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/431759/using-multiple-usb-webcams-in-linux) this pixel format is needed, but when I try to capture video from both webcams the `VIDIOC_STREAMON: No space left on device` error still happening for the second camera, I can only get stereo video at 320x240 resolution!
I tried the following two but does not work for me.

1. `v4l2-ctl --set-fmt-video=width=640,height=480,pixelformat=1`
2. Setting the `FOURCC` to MJPG causes the `HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L: Property <unknown property string>(6) not supported by device` error.

   ```
   # setting the `FOURCC` will cause the 
   # `HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L: Property <unknown property string>(6) not supported by device`
   for p in ports:
       self.caps.append(cv2.VideoCapture(p))
       self.caps[-1].set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'));
   ```

What should I do to get it right at relatively OK resolution?

P.S: All of my USB ports are connected to a single controller!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried building OpenCV from source with `-D WITH_V4L=ON` and `-D WITH_LIBV4L=ON`?